# ios: Json in Socket.io

Tags: ios, json, swift, socket.io

I need to send data over socketio from ios using swift. Data looks like this:

```
{
    birthday: { 
        "date": 24, 
        "month": 12, 
        "year": 1991
    }
}
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
let myJSON = [
    "birthday" : [
        "date": 24,
        "month": 12, 
        "year": 1991
     ]
]
socket.emit("updateUserInfo", myJSON)
```

Please, tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: If you need to encode your dictionary to JSON, use `NSJSONSerialization`. You can follow this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263171/creating-json-in-swift

Comment: Can you add also the error returned by the server?

Comment: It doesn't return any. It just doesn't update thees items. When i send not nested json - all is fine, like this: ["name":"sergey", "surname":"Ovseenko"]

Answer (score 4):

**January 2020**

Asumming that you are using **Socket.IO-Client-Swift** Library

Here is the sample source on how to effectively pass your JSON data.

```swift
// Adopt to SocketData protocol

 struct CustomData : SocketData {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    func socketRepresentation() -> SocketData {
        return ["name": name, "age": age]
    }
 }

// Usage

 socket.emit("myEvent", CustomData(name: "Erik", age: 24))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right that if you have a dictionary to send over socket.io then you don't have to convert it to JSON because the method socket.emit does that for you.

So the syntax you show seems to be correct : `socket.emit("event-as-string", dictionary)`.

You should tell us the exact error you are encountering such as someone can help you.

Comment: "you don't have to convert it to JSON" yeah. great

Answer (score 2):

With **socket.io** you can send a normal object from javascript and it will be converted to **JSON** automatically.

I tested that code and everything is *ok*

```
let myJSON = { birthday: { "date": 24, "month": 12, "year": 1991}};
socket.emit("updateUserInfo", myJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to convert your Swift object to a JSON string. As Eric D. said there's a built in way to convert dictionary to JSON. If you already have a class representation of the data, you can take a look at a Swift class to JSON converter here:

https://gist.github.com/peheje/cc3618253d4f38ea4885

Have you tried just writing it as a string?

```
let myJSON = "[\"birthday\" : [\"date\": 24, \"month\": 12, \"year\": 1991]]"
```

Comment: Yes, i tried just to write as a string... Also i converted to JSON as Eric D said, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you use the escaping character \ before " to actually include the " inside the string instead of terminating it? Also are you sure the server accepts nested JSON?

Comment: Yes, i used \ and server accepts nested json... I don't know, may be problem in socket.io?

Answer (score -1):

Try this may work , internally it's getting object from zero index

```
[{
    birthday: { 
        "date": 24, 
        "month": 12, 
        "year": 1991
    }
}]
```