# Encoding toJSON from Arrays and Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I am trying to create a JSON file from an array that i make inside my application with swift.

I need to encode to JSON an 'Array' because i am creating dictionaries and arrays before and i just combine them to that array.

In my code i have :

```
var order = Array<Any>()
var orderArray = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
var dict = Dictionary<String, Any>()
```

and i put first the orderArray in dict and then the dict inside order.
The output if i print it is correct and it works. The problem is when i try to encode the order(array) into JSON. Then i get the following error:

Cannot invoke 'dataWithJSONObject' with an argument list of type '(Array'

This is the code i use:

```
let json = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(order, options:      NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)
```

If i try the same code with the orderArray for example it works.
The 'Any' i think does the mess. But how could i resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating json in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263171/creating-json-in-swift)

Comment: Other example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325268/convert-array-to-json-string-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: I tried exactly the same thing and i checked exactly the same post. It didnt work. That is why i am asking.

Comment: What is in your order array before you call dataWithJSONObject?

Comment: [[table: name, user: name, items: [[item1: name], [item1: name]]]    This for example is my array