# Sending (POST) Json Array with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, post, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to send an array of JSON-Objects to my server using Alamofire.
As postparameters only `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` are allowed in Alamofire. So I tried to do it with an `NSMutableURLRequest`.
But it doesn't work, too. I am using SwiftyJSON, too.

This is what I trying, but I cant put the Array in the Body.

```
    //testClassList: [TestClass]
    let uri : String = serveraddress + "/SendClassList";

    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: uri)!)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var header : [String:String] = createHeader();

    mutableURLRequest.addValue(header["Authorization"]!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization");
    mutableURLRequest.addValue(header["Content-Type"]!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
    mutableURLRequest.addValue(header["Accept"]!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept");
    do{
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = JSON(testClassList);
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }

    Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest).responseJSON { response in
        if(response.response?.statusCode == 200){
            let resp: String = response.result.value as! String;
            completionHandler?(resp, nil);
        }
}
```

Is there a way to post an Array direct without wrapping it into another JSON like `["list":testClassList]`

(Please only Swift 2.+ Code.)

best regards

Comment: `JSON(testClassList)` creates a SwiftyJSON object, not JSON data or JSON string. You've got that backwards: you should generate a JSON string from JSON data you make from your object.

Comment: So I have to make a JSON string from my array and pass it to the HTTPBody?

Comment: It looks like it answers your question, yes. I have an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263171/creating-json-in-swift/31263337#31263337