# How to convert a String array to Swiftyjson JSON type

Tags: json, swift, http, post, swifty-json

I need to pass an array of string/Int (doesnt matter) as JSON parameter in a HTTP body for a POST request.

```
{
  "par1" : value,
  "par2" : "value2",
  "par3" : ['123:456', '123:234' ...]*
}
```

*My problem is for filling my JSON object with param3 values. In the swift code I have them as an array of Strings.

There are many example of converting a JSON object back to an array of strings/Int, but I can't find it the other way around.

Comment: Check out NSJSONSeralization, it can take Swift types and encode them to JSON.

Comment: Follow the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29625483/2227743 The title says "dictionary" but it also works for arrays.

Comment: Also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263337/2227743

Comment: I already have a WIP impl with NSJSONSerialization @thefredelement but i wish I could use a swiftyJSON solution

Comment: Ok so NSJSONSerialization is the way to go, I already found about this but i was hoping that swiftyJSON had something else. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the way to go is to use `NSJSONSerialization` to generate object encoded in JSON data.