# Construction was too complex to be solved in reasonable time

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift3

I have problem with Swift 3, I am trying to send a request to a server and get JSON, but I get:

> Construction was too complex to be solved in reasonable time.

I tried every way, but it doesn't worked.

```
var userName = "root"
var password = "admin01"
//var LOGIN_TOKEN = 0000000000000000

let parameters = [
    "{\n",
    "    \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\",\n",
    "    \"id\": \"1\",\n",
    "    \"method\": \"call\",\n",
    "    \"params\": [\n",
    "        \"0000000000000000\",\n",
    "        \"session\",\n",
    "        \"login\",\n",
    "        {\n",
    "            \"username\": \"" + userName + "\",\n",
    "            \"password\": \"" + password + "\"\n",
    "        }\n",
    "    ]\n",
    "}"
]

let joiner = ""
let joinedStrings = parameters.joined(separator: joiner)
print("joinedStrings: \(joinedStrings)")

// All three of these calls are equivalent
Alamofire.request("http://192.168.1.1", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
    print("Request: \(response.request)")
    print("Response: \(response.response)")


    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    }
}
```

Now I tryed to creat dic and convert to Json, but after that, I get problem on request there I declare my parameters. they say: use of unresolved identifier dictFromJSON

```
  var userName = "root"
   var password = "admin01"
   //var LOGIN_TOKEN = 0000000000000000

    let jsonObject: [String: Any] =
        ["jsonrpc" : 2.0,
         "id": 1,
         "method": "call",
         "params": [ "00000000000000",
                     "session",
                     "login",
                     [ "username": userName,
                       "password": password]],
         ]
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted)
        // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data

        let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
        // here "decoded" is of type `Any`, decoded from JSON data

        // you can now cast it with the right type
        if let dictFromJSON = decoded as? [String:String] {
            // use dictFromJSON
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }




    // All three of these calls are equivalent
    Alamofire.request("http://192.168.1.1/ubus", method: .post, parameters: dictFromJSON).responseJSON { response in
        print("Request: \(response.request)")
        print("Response: \(response.response)")
```

Comment: Don't create a JSON string manually anyway. Create arrays and dictionaries then convert them to JSON. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263337/2227743

Comment: and now I get error: Extra argument 'method' in call. Could you help me with that?

Comment: This is just an example that happens to be in Swift 2. What's important is the idea. You can find other examples by yourself, there's many.

Comment: I created dic and converted to JSon but I got another proble, please check my question, I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

**According to the document of Alamofire, (you can see [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#post-request-with-url-encoded-parameters)), you don't need to convert the parameters Dictionary to JSON.**

For example,

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": ["a", 1],
    "qux": [
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 3
    ]
]

// All three of these calls are equivalent
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters)
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)

// HTTP body: foo=bar&baz[]=a&baz[]=1&qux[x]=1&qux[y]=2&qux[z]=3
```

OLD:

You should use Dictionay for the parameter actually.

Therefore, instead of declaring the parameter like you did, you should do like this:

```
let parameters = ["jsonrpc" : 2.0,
              "id": 1,
              "method": "call",
              "params": [ "00000000000000",
                          "session",
                          "login",
                          [ "username": userName,
                            "password": password]],
            ]
```

Comment: I tryed this way, but now I got problem with request, I updated my question please check, and help me